# Feeding UCF101 dataset through TensorFlow RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow-datasets

I am currently trying to build an RNN for the UCF101 dataset using TensorFlow.
The dataset can easily be loaded using `tensorflow_datasets` like so:

```
(train, test) = tfds.load('ucf101', split = ['train', 'test'], shuffle_files = True)
print("Training Size: ",len(train)) # 9,537
print("Teset Size: ",len(test)) # 3,783 examples
```

The dataset set is of type `tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.PrefetchDataset' and its shape is (256,256,3).

I then constructed an RNN using tensorflow using the bellow code.

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.SimpleRNN(200, input_shape=(256, 256, 3), return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.SimpleRNN(50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.SimpleRNN(25, return_sequences=False))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

How can I pass my training and test data into the network when the SimpleRNN layer expects "A 3D tensor, with shape [batch, timesteps, feature]". Do I need to reformat the train and test data? if so, to what shape? How can I manipulate the `PrefetchDataset` without loading all 7gb into memory. Thank you in advance.

I tried to pass my preloaded dataset into my network. I was expecting the dataset to already be the correct shape for training purposes.

Comment: The inputs you have is `[batch, time, width, height, channels]`. You need to convert them to `[batch, time, features]` to pass to your model. So you can add a CNN model (a pretrianed 2d or 3d) and convert the videos to `[batch, time, features]`

Comment: @V.M thanks for the reply! Just to confirm, I need to convert  (batch_size, time, 256, 256, 3) into (batch_size, time,  196,608) ? (256*256*3 = 196,608)

Comment: That is one way of doing it. But the model won't learn very well. Instead pass (batch, time, 256, 256,3) to a pretrained model like resnet which will output features for each `time`. You can then convert to (batch, time, features)

Comment: https://keras.io/examples/vision/video_classification/